# Java Jackson writing object twice

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following class which contains a String field and a Map field. I want to use Jackson to serialize it to json.

```
public class Mapping 

    private String mAttribute;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, String> mMap;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        //some logic to populate map
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void put(// some params) {
        //some more logic
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "attribute")
    public String getAttribute() {
        return mAttribute;
    }

    public void setAttribute(String aAttribute) {
        mAttribute= aAttribute;
    }
}
```

I instantiate a `Mapping` object and then use `ObjectMapper` to write it to a file.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.writeValue(destFile, myMappingObject);
```

For some reason, it's writing the `Mapping` instance `myMappingObject` twice. I'm assuming I've not set some visibility option somewhere but I don't know where.

The json looks like this, only it comes up twice in the file.

```
{
    "attribute" : "someValue",
    "map-key1" : "map-value1",
    "map-key2" : "map-value2"
}
```

There's [this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-384?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel), but apparently it was fixed in previous version of Jackson. I also tried changing the name of the method to `random()` and it still gets called twice (the number of times it should).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the above class. I was using another class that had a list of `Mapping`s. Before:

```
public class MappingsList {
    @JsonProperty
    private List<Mapping> mappings;

    public List<Mapping> getMappings() {return mappings;}
}
```

After:

```
public class MappingsList {        
    private List<Mapping> mappings;

    @JsonProperty
    public List<Mapping> getMappings() {return mappings;}
}
```

And it worked. The cause is that the ObjectMapper was seeing two (2) properties in the `MappingsList` class and therefore doing serialization on both. First it would create json for the `mappings` field and then again for the `getMappings()` method.